# AutoResetEvent Reset immediately after Set

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

Consider the following pattern:

```
private AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void Work()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        signal.Set();
        //has a waiting thread definitely been signaled by now?
        signal.Reset();
    }
}

public void WaitForNextEvent()
{
    signal.WaitOne();
}
```

The purpose of this pattern is to allow external consumers to wait for a certain event (e.g. - a message arriving). `WaitForNextEvent` is not called from within the class.

To give an example that should be familiar, consider `System.Diagnostics.Process`. It exposes an `Exited` event, but it also exposes a `WaitForExit` method, which allows the caller to wait synchronously until the process exits. this is what I am trying to achieve here.

The reason I need `signal.Reset()` is that if a thread calls `WaitForNextEvent` **after** `signal.Set()` has already been called (or in other words, if `.Set` was called when no threads were waiting), it returns immediately, as the event has already been previously signaled.

### The question

- Is it guaranteed that a thread calling `WaitForNextEvent()` will be signaled **before** `signal.Reset()` is called? If not, what are other solutions for implementing a `WaitFor` method?

Comment: It isn't clear (at least for me) what you are trying to do here. Could you explain what you would like the threads flow to be?

Comment: An `AutoResetEvent` automatically resets after one thread has successfully waited for it via `WaitOne()` so you should *not* need to call `signal.Reset()`.

Comment: Yes, it's the same with a ManualResetEvent (see [this question from me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067369/manualreseteventslim-calling-set-followed-immediately-by-reset-doesnt-re)). However, the big issue for me is why the OP thinks he needs to call `.Reset()` for an `AutoResetEvent`...

Comment: I think you're using the wrong synchronization primitive. If you could describe what behaviour you're aiming for in a bit more detail, we might be able to help out. E.g. a [`Barrier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) lets a specific number of threads all rendezvous and then move forward into a new phase together.

Comment: I've updated my question to better explain my intent.

Comment: Why not use a semaphore instead, (System.Threading.Semaphore)?  It maintains state - a count, and so it would not matter if the signal occurred before the wait.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure I understand how a semaphore would help me here. The intended behavior is that a thread calling `WaitOne` **after** `Set` has been called will block until the next `Set` is called. Could you give an example of how that would work with a semaphore?

Comment: @Rotem - uhh.. OK.  I was a little unclear on your exact requirement so, luckily, I commented instead of answering:)

Comment: I was going to write an answer that involved using a `TaskCompletionSource` - swapping an old one with a new one before setting the result on the old one. But then realised that if multiple threads were waiting on one, then they would *all* be released, whereas with the `AutoResetEvent`, only *one* thread can be released.

Comment: I'll say that the example you give and the objective you have are totally different. `To give an example that should be familiar, consider System.Diagnostics.Process` Here the event can happen only once. The Process has Exited or it hasn't. After it has exited it can't "restart" and "reexit". The example you gave was a tight cycle with a lock/unlock after each cycle.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But the example he gives now, the `WaitForExit `, all the threads waiting will be started after the exit :-)

Comment: @xanatos - you're write. For some reason I had it in mind that an `AutoResetEvent` would only release one thread.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You were not wrong about that. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx : **"For an EventWaitHandle with EventResetMode.AutoReset (including AutoResetEvent), the Set method releases a single thread."**

Comment: The `Process` example is completely different because it is only signalled once. Neither `ManualResetEvent` nor `AutoResetEvent` will work in this situation - [they can't be "pulsed" reliably](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/05/346888.aspx). Matthew's answer uses `Monitor` which correctly avoids this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent`, use this:

```
public sealed class Signaller
{
    public void PulseAll()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
        }
    }

    public void Pulse()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
        }
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public bool Wait(int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return Monitor.Wait(_lock, timeoutMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    private readonly object _lock = new object();
}
```

Then change your code like so:

```
private Signaller signal = new Signaller();

private void Work()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        signal.Pulse(); // Or signal.PulseAll() to signal ALL waiting threads.
    }
}

public void WaitForNextEvent()
{
    signal.Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee. This:

```
AutoResetEvent flag = new AutoResetEvent(false);

new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
    Console.WriteLine("Work Item Started");
    flag.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Work Item Executed");
}).Start();

// For fast systems, you can help by occupying processors.
for (int ix = 0; ix < 2; ++ix)
{
    new Thread(() => { while (true) ; }).Start();
}

Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("Sleeped");

flag.Set();
// Decomment here to make it work
//Thread.Sleep(1000);

flag.Reset();
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
Console.ReadLine();
```

won't print "Work Item Executed" on my system. If I add a `Thread.Sleep` between the `Set` and the `Reset` it prints it. Note that this is very processor dependent, so you could have to create tons of threads to "fill" the CPUs. On my PC it's reproducible 50% of the times :-)

For the Exited:

```
readonly object mylock = new object();
```

then somewhere:

```
lock (mylock)
{
    // Your code goes here
}
```

and the `WaitForExit`:

```
void WaitForExit()
{
    lock (mylock) ;
    // exited
}

void bool IsExited()
{
    bool lockTacken = false;

    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(mylock, ref lockTacken);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTacken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(mylock);
        }
    }

    return lockTacken;
}
```

Note that the `lock` construct isn't compatible with `async`/`await` (as aren't nearly all the locking primitives of .NET)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx)s:

```
private volatile TaskCompletionSource<int> signal = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

private void Work()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        var oldSignal = signal;
        signal = new TaskCompletionSource<int>()
        //has a waiting thread definitely been signaled by now?
        oldSignal.SetResult(0);
    }
}

public void WaitForNextEvent()
{
    signal.Task.Wait();
}
```

By the time that the code calls `SetResult`, no new code entering `WaitForNextEvent` can obtain the `TaskCompletionSource` that is being signalled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not guaranteed.

However, your logic flow is not understood by me. If your main thread `Set`s the signal, why should it wait until that signal reaches its destination? Wouldn't it be better to continue your "after signal set" logic **in that** thread which was waiting?

If you cannot do that, I recommend you to use second `WaitHandle` to signal the first thread that the second one has reveiced the signal. But I cannot see any pros of such a strategy.