# How to make a slightly modified AutoResetEvent class?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I need a synchronizing class that behaves exactly like the **AutoResetEvent** class, but with one minor exception:

A call to the *Set()* method must release *all* waiting threads, and not just one.

How can I construct such a class? I am simply out of ideas?

- Martin.

Comment: [Monitor.Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: @L.B: I think you mean [`Monitor.PulseAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulseall(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Monitor.PulseAll() requires you to own a lock on an object - AutoResetEvent has no such requirements for its somewhat corresponding Set() method. I cannot imagine how to build my class on the Monitor construct???

Comment: @MartinChristiansen What about posting the real problem you want to solve? Maybe your question is an [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem)

Comment: This **is** my real problem. I simply find it challenging that such a simple class with such a precise semantic seems so hard (impossible?) to implement, even with all those great building blocks you have available in the .NET framework.

Comment: Can you give us a simple example that requires this behavior?  Why are these threads waiting and why do they need to release at the same time.  It is much better to have a design where you start the thread and then let it run until it completes.  Not a thread that needs to stop and start during it's lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for all your thougts and inputs which I have read with great interest. I did some more searching here on Stackoverflow, and suddenly I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609285/autoresetevent-reset-immediately-after-set?rq=1), whcih turned out to be just what I was looking for. By cutting it down to just the two methods I need, I ended up with this small class:

```
public sealed class Signaller
{
    public void PulseAll()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
        }
    }

    public bool Wait(TimeSpan maxWaitTime)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return Monitor.Wait(_lock, maxWaitTime);
        }
    }

    private readonly object _lock = new object();
}
```

and it does excactly what it should! I'm amazed that a solution could be that simple, and I love such simplicity. I'ts beautiful. Thank you, Matthew Watson!

- Martin.

Answer (score 1):

So you have multiple threads doing a .WaitOne() and you want to release them?

Use the ManualResetEvent class and all the waiting threads should release...

Comment: I already tried that, but I get the following problems: 1) A call to Set() leaves the gate open, allowing further threads that call WaitOne() to pass through until you manually call Reset(), which will close the gate. You cannot guarantee that only the threads that were waiting will pass through while open. 2) If you call Set() and then immediately after call Reset(), no waiting threads are released. After a call to Set() the blocked threads start to flow, but not all at once. I tried a Thread.Sleep(10) between Set() and Reset() and only 8 of 20 blocked threads were let through.

Comment: @Martin without further synchronization there is no observable difference between a thread arriving before you call set or afterwards. What you seem to want is an atomic release all threads function - not exactly trivial but doable (a monitor and a int is really all you need afaics). The bigger problem is that I can't think of a single situation where needing such functionality isn't a sign of a bigger design flaw. You should describe what you're actually trying to achieve, there might be a better way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might try.

Using a Barrier object add conditionally adding threads too it and signaling them.

The other might be to use a publisher subscriber setup like in RX. Each thread waits on an object that it passes to a collection. When you want to call 'set' loop over a snapshot of it calling set on each member.

Or you could try bears.

Comment: I spent hours on other solutions with no results, but bears solved it for me in a few minutes.  Now, to pay them...

Answer (score 0):

If the event is being referenced by all threads in a common field or property, you could replace the common field or property with a new non-signaled event and then signal the old one. It has some cost to it since you'll be regularly creating new synchronization objects, but it would work. Here's an example of how I would do that:

```
public static class Example
{
    private static volatile bool stopRunning;
    private static ReleasingAutoResetEvent myEvent;

    public static void RunExample()
    {
        using (Example.myEvent = new ReleasingAutoResetEvent())
        {
            WaitCallback work = new WaitCallback(WaitThread);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(work, i.ToString());
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                Example.myEvent.Set();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

            Example.stopRunning = true;
            Example.myEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    private static void WaitThread(object state)
    {
        while (!Example.stopRunning)
        {
            Example.myEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is released!", state);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class ReleasingAutoResetEvent : IDisposable
{
    private volatile ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void Set()
    {
        ManualResetEvent eventToSet = this.manualResetEvent;
        this.manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        eventToSet.Set();
        eventToSet.Dispose();
    }

    public bool WaitOne()
    {
        return this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public bool WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        return this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout);
    }

    public bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne(timeout);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.manualResetEvent.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more lightweight solution you could try that uses the Monitor class to lock and unlock objects is below. However, I'm not as happy with the cleanup story for this version of ReleasingAutoResetEvent since Monitor may hold a reference to it and keep it alive indefinitely if it is not properly disposed.

There are a few limitations/gotchas with this implementation. First, the thread that creates this object will be the only one that will be able to signal it with a call to Set; other threads that attempt to do the same thing will receive a SynchronizationLockException. Second, the thread that created it will never be able to wait on it successfully since it already owns the lock. This will only be an effective solution if you have exactly one controlling thread and several other waiting threads.

```
public static class Example
{
    private static volatile bool stopRunning;
    private static ReleasingAutoResetEvent myEvent;

    public static void RunExample()
    {
        using (Example.myEvent = new ReleasingAutoResetEvent())
        {
            WaitCallback work = new WaitCallback(WaitThread);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(work, i.ToString());
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                Example.myEvent.Set();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

            Example.stopRunning = true;
            Example.myEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    private static void WaitThread(object state)
    {
        while (!Example.stopRunning)
        {
            Example.myEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is released!", state);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class ReleasingAutoResetEvent : IDisposable
{
    private volatile object lockObject = new object();

    public ReleasingAutoResetEvent()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(this.lockObject);
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        object objectToSignal = this.lockObject;
        object objectToLock = new object();

        Monitor.Enter(objectToLock);
        this.lockObject = objectToLock;
        Monitor.Exit(objectToSignal);
    }

    public void WaitOne()
    {
        object objectToMonitor = this.lockObject;
        Monitor.Enter(objectToMonitor);
        Monitor.Exit(objectToMonitor);
    }

    public bool WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        object objectToMonitor = this.lockObject;
        bool succeeded = Monitor.TryEnter(objectToMonitor, millisecondsTimeout);

        if (succeeded)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(objectToMonitor);
        }

        return succeeded;
    }

    public bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        object objectToMonitor = this.lockObject;
        bool succeeded = Monitor.TryEnter(objectToMonitor, timeout);

        if (succeeded)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(objectToMonitor);
        }

        return succeeded;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(this.lockObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Poking about at related answers, it looks like the answer for question [AutoResetEvent Reset immediately after Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609285/autoresetevent-reset-immediately-after-set?rq=1) is better than mine for using Monitor to accomplish your goal. For your scenario, you would want to call the PulseAll method that it offers to release all currently waiting threads.